# Creating a PDF reader in C++

Tags: c++

So I wanna make a PDF reader using C++ as a hobby project. The problem is I am not finding much of head start so if anyone has worked on similar project please guide me, a few web links would be great! I will be using windows environment and Visual studio.

Answer (score 10):

If you want to simply "host" an existing PDF reader (such as Acrobat or Foxit) in your own window, then you'll want to look in to [ActiveX](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315847).

Alternately, if you want to do your own PDF decoding, then the best place to start would be find a soft couch and cozy up with the [PDF format specification](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/pdf/pdf_reference.html), and in particular, [ISO 32000-1](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf). It's a real page-turner.

Answer (score 4):

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/pdf/pdf_reference.html

Adobe's publication about the details of the PDF file format.

There are PDF components as well, if you want to go that route, but the majority of them are either not free, or already have a UI of their own.  Just tossing a PDF component into a form doesn't strike me as much of a hobby project.  :)

Comment: I agree to that, I dont need components I would want to write them on my own, and thats why I am asking if any1 knows of any other route to start off with. my basic aim is very simple, just want to be able to open an exsisting pdf file and display it, lets start with simple text pdf and then add more support!

Comment: I'd start with just being able to read a PDF file and dump details about the objects in it.  Once you can do that, it gets a bit easier to understand the structure of the document, and from there to output the objects within to a page-sized image -- starting with the easy stuff like text, and moving up to stuff like images.  Once you can do that, you've effectively rendered the PDF.

Answer (score 1):

You might find [this article](http://www.apriorit.com/our-experience/articles/9-sd-articles/61-reg-file-parser) on parsing Reg files using Boost Spirit a useful starter. I've used Spirit before for parsing complex data but I think you're biting off a mighty big challenge!

If you want to look at existing parsers, try [PoDoFo](http://podofo.sourceforge.net/) in C++ or the lexing side of [Panda](http://sourceforge.net/projects/panda/), in C.